# compatibility routines for supporting only iOS devices with cameras

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm working on a universal app that uses the camera on iOS devices and which will require iOS5+.

I'm trying to sort out the whole *how many cameras/what size images possible/video* capable compatibility issues. After searching around a bit it occurs to me that someone might have either collected the data in an easily accessible form for all this stuff - or even better, written some routines to use at runtime. I need to do the standard stuff - figuring out how many cameras, image resolutions, etc.

I know all this info is available through the API with some digging around. Before I reinvent this wheel, has anyone written this sort of thing already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be exactly what you are looking for:

https://github.com/MugunthKumar/DeviceHelper

That said, if you are using something like a UIImagePicker, it has it's own functions like:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
```